# "Automation Error" "Unspecified Error" When Using Excel-VBA and ADODB Objects

Tags: sql, vba

I am creating a macro that looks through a folder, performs a SQL operation on each of the documents, and copies the results into another workbook; however, every time I debug and hit the `Set rs = cn.Execute(sql)` line I get an

> "Automation Error" "Unspecified Error" .

The even weirder thing is that when I just run the code, I get an

> "Execute of object _Connection failed" error.

I have tested the SQL code in microsoft SQL server already and each of these statements are almost verbatim  with code I have previously got to work.

```vb
Option Explicit


Sub hardnessTests()

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandling

    Dim filename As Variant, n As Long
    n = 0

    Call turnOff

    filename = Dir("T:\Marketing\Data Analytics\GIS Data\Water Quality Portal Data\County Summary Results\*")

    While filename <> ""

        Dim file As String, cn As Object, rs As Object, sql As String, hardField As ADODB.Field
        file = "T:\Marketing\Data Analytics\GIS Data\Water Quality Portal Data\County Summary Results\" & filename

        Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

        With cn
            .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
            .connectionstring = "Data Source=" & file & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;Readonly=false;IMEX=0"";"
            .Open
        End With

        sql = "SELECT c.STATEFP, c.COUNTYFP, AVG(CAST(a.ResultMeasureValue AS NUMERIC)) AS Average_Surface_Water_Hardness, COUNT(a.ResultMeasureValue) AS Number_Of_Surface_Water_Tests, " & _
              "AVG(CAST(b.ResultMeasureValue AS NUMERIC)) AS Average_Groundwater_Hardness, COUNT(b.ResultMeasureValue) AS Number_Of_Groundwater_Tests " & _
              "FROM (SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE CAST(LEFT(ActivityStartDate, 4) AS NUMERIC) >= 2010 and ActivityMediaSubdivisionName = 'Surface Water') a, " & _
              "(SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE CAST(LEFT(ActivityStartDate, 4) AS NUMERIC) >= 2010 AND ActivityMediaSubdivisionName = 'Groundwater') b, " & _
              "(SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE CAST(LEFT(ActivityStartDate, 4) AS NUMERIC) >= 2010 ) c GROUP BY c.STATEFP, c.COUNTYFP ORDER BY c.STATEFP, c.COUNTYFP"

        Set rs = cn.Execute(sql)

        Dim wb As Workbook, fieldCount As Long
        fieldCount = 0
        Set wb = Workbooks.Add
        wb.SaveAs "T:\Marketing\Data Analytics\GIS Data\Water Quality Portal Data\County Summary Results\ALL_HARDNESS.xlsx"

        If n = 0 Then
            wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
        Else:
            wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").End(xlDown).CopyFromRecordset rs
        End If

        filename = Dir
        n = n + 1

    Wend

    For Each hardField In rs.Fields
        wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Offset(0, fieldCount) = hardField.Name
        fieldCount = fieldCount + 1
    Next hardField

    Call turnOn

Exit Sub

ErrorHandling:
    MsgBox ("Source: " & Err.Source & vbNewLine & "Number: " & Err.Number & vbNewLine & "Description: " & Err.Description & vbNewLine & "Help Context: " & Err.HelpContext)
Done:
    End Sub

Private Sub turnOff()

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub

Private Sub turnOn()

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: did you set a reference to MS Active Data Objects Library ?

Comment: does the code compile ?

Comment: @Patrick Honorez - For my References, I have: VBA, Microsoft Excel 16.0 Library, OLE Automation, Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects Recordset 6.0 Library, and Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library. My code does compile

Comment: ADO SQL is not the same as SQL Server's SQL - it's closer to MS Access's version. In this case you can't set a shortname for a record set just by adding a letter, you need to use the keyword AS -so "select name from mydata as a" rather than "select name from mydata a". This may not be the only problem of course.

Comment: @HarassedDad it's not ADO, it's `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0`. If it's SQL Server running the query, the syntax is T-SQL syntax, even though the connection is through ADODB. It's the provider that matters. But yeah, ACE.OLEDB isn't T-SQL ;-)

Comment: @HarassedDad I changed it and no luck, but thanks for the idea. I kind of just assumed the SQL Server would be the same because they're both Microsoft

Comment: Try manually setting up the connection and query through the UI first, you'll probably get more meaningful error messages

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with UI. Could you send me some resources pertaining to it? Thanks

Comment: I mean the Excel UI - from the "Data" tab...

Comment: I'm still lost. I've never heard of Excel UI before

Comment: UI = User Interface. He means use the menus rather than VB to make the connection - that should give you better error messages for debugging

Comment: @MathieuGuindon It gave me the same error : \